# Why i get unicode from html?

Tags: java, parsing, unicode, encode

I wrtite parser without third-party libraries. Get html code from web site - http://www.cnn.com/ - but some part of code has unicode instead symbols, for example: "**\u003c**br/>Sign in to your TV service provider to get access to **\u003c**br/>" i think it is problem with encode - how i can fix it? Sorry for my English. Thank you.

```
    public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String commandLine = Scraper.readLineFromConsole();
    Reader reader = Scraper.getReader(commandLine);
    Scraper.writeInFileFromURL(reader);
}

public static class Scraper {
    public static void writeInFileFromURL(Reader out) {
        Reader reader = out;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);

        try {
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("newFile.txt");
            String htmltext;
            while (br.ready()) {
                htmltext = br.readLine();
                writer.write(new String(htmltext));
            }
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static String readLineFromConsole() {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String commandLine = null;
        try {
            commandLine = reader.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return commandLine;
    }

    public static Reader getReader(String url)
            throws IOException {
        // Retrieve from Internet.
        if (url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:")) {
            URLConnection conn = new URL(url).openConnection();
            return new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
        }
        // Retrieve from file.
        else {
            return new FileReader(url);
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Why you reinvent the wheel?

Comment: did you try to tell the reader the charset you use? for example with `new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(yourFileName), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))`

Comment: Looks like the source is written that way to me, as a way to escape XML/XHTML in their JS code. I would expect the resulting HTML produced after execution not to contain these

Comment: Jens, if you ask about cycle "while" - it's rudiment

Comment: msrd0, i tried your way - it doesn't help =/